# Spring EL - "There is still more data in the expression"

Tags: spring, spring-el

Is it possible to parse an expression like the one shown below, where I call a method and would like to have text after the result of that method call?

```
String expression = "obj.someMethod()'test'";
ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser(); 
Expression expression = parser.parseExpression(expression);
```

When I run code like the one below I get the following error:

`org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1041E:(pos 23): After parsing a valid expression, there is still more data in the expression: 'test'`

If I remove the `'test'` string, then it parsers and evaluates correctly.

Comment: ? do you perhaps mean `"obj.someMethod('test')"`?

Comment: No, I mean exactly how it looks.  I want the method to execute and the return value of that essentially concatenated with "test".  Initially I tried surrounding the method call with `#{}`, but that did not work.

Comment: then I guess you want `"obj.someMethod() + 'test'"`

Comment: Hmm...I guess that would make sense considering it would be an expression.  I was under the impression the EL parser would leave strings surrounded with single quotes as-is, and evaluate all else, but sounds like that's incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if it is Expression language it is based on the core programming language and follows with its rules.

So, if you use `+` operator to concat method result with the string in Java, you should do the same in SpEL:

```
"obj.someMethod() + 'test'"
```

is correct answer for you.

As well as you can use :

```
"obj.someMethod().concat('test')"
```

if `someMethod()` returns `String`, of course.